# ViewPager doesnt inflate all XML layout files

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I want to create Tabs within tabs in my app. I have created a TabLayout in my MainActivity XML file along with ViewPager. I have then created another XML file which contains the inner TabLayout with its corresponding ViewPager. Now, when I run my app, I can see inflated views of all other tabs except my first tab(home icon tab). Also, I have a CardView to be displayed when one of my inner tabs is selected which is not being seen. Please help!
This is my MainActivity.java code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager viewPagerOuter, viewPagerInner;
    TabLayout tabLayoutouter, tabLayoutinner;

    public static class InnerFragment extends Fragment{
    private static final String TAB_POSITION = "tab_position";
    View rootView;
    public InnerFragment(){

    }
    public static InnerFragment newInstance(int tabPosition){
        InnerFragment fragment = new InnerFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(TAB_POSITION, tabPosition);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        int tabPosition = args.getInt(TAB_POSITION);
        switch (tabPosition){
            case 0:{
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view_layout, container, false);
                break;
            }
            case 1:{
                TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tv.setText("Text in tab #" + tabPosition);
                rootView = tv;
                break;
            }
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
static class InnerPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
    public InnerPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return InnerFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        String x = "";
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                x = "feed"; break;
            case 1:
                x = "events"; break;
        }
        return x;
    }
}

public static class OuterFragment extends Fragment{
    private static final String TAB_POSITION1 = "tab_position";
    View rootView;
    public OuterFragment(){

    }
    public static OuterFragment newInstance(int tabPosition){
        OuterFragment fragment1 = new OuterFragment();
        Bundle args1 = new Bundle();
        args1.putInt(TAB_POSITION1, tabPosition);
        fragment1.setArguments(args1);
        return fragment1;
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater1, ViewGroup container1, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        Bundle args1 = getArguments();
        int tabPosition = args1.getInt(TAB_POSITION1);
        switch (tabPosition){
            case 0:{
                rootView = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.inner_tab_layout, container1, false);
                break;
            }
            default:{
                TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tv.setText("Text in tab #" + tabPosition);
                rootView = tv;
                break;
            }
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
static class OuterPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
    public OuterPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return OuterFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {return null;}
}
final int icons[] = new int[]{R.drawable.ic_chat_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_notifications_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_person_black_24dp};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    InnerPagerAdapter innerPagerAdapter = new InnerPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    OuterPagerAdapter outerPagerAdapter = new OuterPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPagerOuter = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpagerouter);
    viewPagerOuter.setAdapter(outerPagerAdapter);
    tabLayoutouter = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayoutouter);

    final LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
    final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.inner_tab_layout, null);
    viewPagerInner = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpagerinner);
    viewPagerInner.setAdapter(innerPagerAdapter);
    tabLayoutinner = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayoutinner);
    tabLayoutinner.setupWithViewPager(viewPagerInner);
}
}
```

And this is XML file of MainActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayoutouter"
        android.support.tabIndicatorColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/background_light">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpagerouter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_create_black_24dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is inner_tab_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayoutinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorBlack">
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpagerinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am sorry for posting such long bits of code. Please don't mind..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `viewPagerInner`, `tabLayoutinner` and `innerPagerAdapter` code to `OuterFragment`.

**1.** Update your `OuterFragment`  as below:

```
public static class OuterFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAB_POSITION1 = "tab_position";
    View rootView;

    ViewPager viewPagerInner;
    TabLayout tabLayoutinner;

    public OuterFragment(){

    }
    public static OuterFragment newInstance(int tabPosition){
        OuterFragment fragment1 = new OuterFragment();
        Bundle args1 = new Bundle();
        args1.putInt(TAB_POSITION1, tabPosition);
        fragment1.setArguments(args1);
        return fragment1;
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater1, ViewGroup container1, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        Bundle args1 = getArguments();
        int tabPosition = args1.getInt(TAB_POSITION1);
        switch (tabPosition){
            case 0:{
                rootView = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.inner_tab_layout, container1, false);

                viewPagerInner = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpagerinner);
                tabLayoutinner = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabLayoutinner);

                InnerPagerAdapter innerPagerAdapter = new InnerPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());

                viewPagerInner.setAdapter(innerPagerAdapter);
                tabLayoutinner.setupWithViewPager(viewPagerInner);

                break;
            }
            default:{
                TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tv.setText("Text in tab #" + tabPosition);
                rootView = tv;
                break;
            }
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**2.** Update `onCreate()` method as below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPagerOuter = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpagerouter);
    tabLayoutouter = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayoutouter);

    OuterPagerAdapter outerPagerAdapter = new OuterPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPagerOuter.setAdapter(outerPagerAdapter);
    tabLayoutouter.setupWithViewPager(viewPagerOuter);
}
```

Hope this will work~

Comment: In case 0, it says getSupportFragmentManager() cannot be accessed from a static context.

Comment: Use getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(); I have updated my answer.

Comment: I found a small problem occurring. After I scroll to the very last tab in my outer TabLayout and come back to the first, I find that the card view isn't displayed. Also, the number of tabs in the inner TabLayout has increased...I cant figure out why...any ideas?